# Difference between "GRUB2 for EFI" and "GRUB2" in bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, grub-efi

I am making a software to customize **GRUB** and **Bootloader** and I have a similar built-in software in Linux which changes some configuration of  **Bootloader.** There are two options and I want to know the differences between these two.

**Option 1:** GRUB2 for EFI

[image]

**Option 2:** GRUB2

[image]

What are the differences between these two?

Comment: grub2 for EFI, is for EFI systems. grub2 is for Legacy systems

Comment: My system supports Both UEFI and Legacy boot . Can I use any of the options?

Comment: I installed My OS in UEFI mode.

Comment: You will use the grub you need for the specific boot. For example, if you boot in UEFI mode you will need to use the grub for EFI. GRUB won't work.

Comment: Grub2 has different packages for UEFI - grub-efi-amd64 (all 64 bit pc) and grub-pc for BIOS boot of PC. http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/